# Using gem postgis_adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, postgis

Adding a polygon?

`local = Local.new(:geom => **Polygon('-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571,-71.1776820268866 42.3903701743239,-71.1776063012595 42.3903825660754')**)`

Error: syntax error, unexpected tFLOAT, expecting '>'

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a polygon:

```
Polygon.from_coordinates([[[-71.1776585052917,42.3902909739571],[-71.1776820268866,42.3903701743239],[-71.1776063012595,42.3903825660754],[-71.1776585052917,42.3902909739571]]], 4326)
```

Make sure the exterior linear ring is closed (i.e., triangles have four points). I'm also setting an SRID=4326 which is a guess that you are using WGS 84.